# Google search from Terminal

Tags: bash, google-search

I am trying to write a script  so as to **Google-search** in terminal. Below is the code :

**google.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Searching for : $@"
for term in $@ ; do
    echo "$term"
    $search = $search%20$term
done
    open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$search"
```

Whenever I try to run the script as :

```
./google.sh some string
```

I get the error as :

```
Searching for : some string
some
./google.sh: line 5: =: command not found
string
./google.sh: line 5: =: command not found
```

Also the google home page opens up in the browser.Please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: there should be no space before and after `=`, use `search=$search..`

Comment: This is a bash script, not Python

Comment: yeah I edited it now..my bad :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got what was the problem. These are the modifications that I made and my code worked.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Searching for : $@"
for term in $@ ; do
    echo "$term"
    search="$search%20$term"
done
    open "http://www.google.com/search?q=$search"
```

1. Removed `$` from `search` at line 5
2. Put **`$search%20$term`** within quotes as `"$search%20$term"`
3. And as suggested removed spaces from line 5.

Comment: when i try like this "$ sh google.sh some string", why it says below error 
"Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console"

Comment: Its trying to open the default browser and facing problems during that...which is your default browser??and also which os are you using?

Comment: Browser : firefox, OS : ubuntu

Comment: Then instead of **open** try using **xdg-open**. I am using mac , that's why I have used open.

Answer (score 1):

I've made this custom aliases. Works for me. OSX

Hope this helps someone!

I added this commands to my `.zshrc`

```sh
alias chrome='{read -r arr; open -a "Google Chrome" "${arr}"} <<<'

alias browser='{read -r arr; chrome ${arr} } <<<'

alias google='{read -r arr; browser "https://google.com/search?q=${arr}";} <<<'
```

Example:
`google 'How do I google from terminal?'`

It will open browser of your choice. Chrome for me, but you can also use Safari or Firefox. By passing arguments right into search query you are able to go directly to search results!

Comment: Searching without opening a web browser, so the result could be piped.

Comment: If you want to pipe resulting links you have to process what's returned. Meaning you're going to parse dom. That's whole another task. My answer is only for handful searching nothing more :)

Comment: Perhaps I was thinking too techie 

Answer (score 1):

For searching in Google, I have this:

> [googleSearch](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/googleSearch) [query]

....................